# Shopware6.5 App Twig Get Shopware Storefront Version?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I was not able to receive the current Storefront Version via Twig, is there no global variable available to read out?

I also tried to read the composer.json, but failed, maybe the app has not enough rights to access it.

```
            {% set composer_json_path = path('base_path') ~ 'composer.json' %}
            {% set composer_json = file_get_contents(composer_json_path) %}
            {% set composer_data = composer_json|json_decode() %}
            {% set shopware_sf_version = composer_data.require['shopware/storefront']|replace({'~v': ''})|float %}

            Shopware_Version: {{ shopware_sf_version }} !
```

Is it possible to retrieve the Storefront Version, the goal is, I'd like to change a small section in the code depending if it is >=6.4 or >=6.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with `6.5.1.0` [you can use `version_compare` with the new global `shopware.version`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/changelog/release-6-5-1-0/2023-04-17-add-shopware-version-to-app-scripts.md).

```
{% if version_compare('6.5.2', shopware.version, '<=') %}
    {# 6.5.2 or lower compatible code #}
{% else %}
    {# 6.5.3 or higher compatible code #}    
{% endif %}
```

You could then use it in scripts for [data loading hooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference) to set an extension to the page object and use the extension in the corresponding templates.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of a possibility to do this with versions prior to `6.5.1.0`.

Comment: That's awesome, I cannot use it for 6.4 but from 6.5.1 then, that's cool 